# Inference logic rule selection problem

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chaining, inference

Tommy, jill and travelor belong to the Sc club.Every member of sc club is either a surfer or a bike rider or both.No bike rider likes a rainy day and all the surfers like a sunny day.Jill like whatever Tommy likes and likes whatever tommy dislikes.Tommy likes a rainy day and a sunny day.

I want to represent the above information in first order predicate logic in such a way that I can represent the question " who is a member of SC club who is a bike rider but not a surfer?" as a predicate logic expression.

What first order inference rule I should pick- forward chaining, backward chaining, or resolution refutation.??

Comment: sucks....is there any body who can answer my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off this question sounds like it is being asked directly out of a book.  If that is the case, it might help if you reference the book in your question.  If you are truly stuck after trying to work it out, then ask yourself this...

How does each inference rule work, and what purpose does it serve toward finding solutions in first order logic problems?  Once you know that, either...

- you wont understand it, but you will have a better question to ask about a particular technique
- the obvious answer will jump out at you
- you will realize which of those techniques can work for your problem and just choose one

Showing that you have taken some time to try and figure out the problem before posting a book style question on stackoverflow will make other people more likely to help you.  You will also have questions that show your lack of conceptual understanding, which is a very good reason to post a question here, as opposed to "answer my homework" sounding questions such as this.